# Начинающий веб разработчик 

Tags: javascript, html, css

Прошу подсказать,на каких сайтах я могу выучиться и познать создание сайтов. Где обучат как следует и желательно бесплатно

Comment: +1 - вопрос понравился моей жене

Answer (score 2):

WEB разработка начинается с языка разметки [HTML](https://html5book.ru/html-html5/), это основа. Затем можно почитать на досуге [CSS](https://html5book.ru/css-css3/). В этом случае уже можно будет создать(или сверстать) web-страницу, этот файл будет с расширением HTML и любой браузер его поймет. Для того, чтобы начать писать HTML и CSS достаточно программы [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).

Вторым шагом, захочется оживить страницу, добавить динамики так сказать. Тут уже начинается программирование (Front-end). Здесь неплохо изучить [JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/). Фреймворки советовать не буду, когда понадобится сам поймёшь что тебе нужно.

Третьим захочется сделать так, чтобы страницы генерировались в зависимости от каких либо условий. Или например позволять пользователям взаимодействовать с сайтом (регистрация, общение, тесты и т.д.). Тут нам понадобится [PHP](http://php.su/). На самом деле не обязательно PHP, есть много других языков, но я задачи на стороне сервера решаю именно на PHP. Чтобы писать код на PHP понадобится сервер (или упростим, нам нужен [хостинг](https://beget.com/)), хотя можно развернуть это дело и у себя дома, но какой смысл, если мы хотим размещать сайт в интернете. Кстати говоря PHP в голом виде это круто, но ещё больше крутости будет после изучения SQL для общения с базой данных - обладая таким багажом уже можно замутить довольно крутые, серьёзные вещи. Но будем двигаться дальше, поняв как работает протокол HTTP - а это довольно просто, мы можем задействовать AJAX. Познав все эти прелести ты будешь ограничен лишь своей фантазией!

И так на будущее, многие вещи уже изобретены и ими можно пользоваться, чтобы сэкономить время:

Чтобы не заморачиваться с дизайном - [Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-4.ru/)

Ускорить разработку на JS - [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Парсим сайты легко и быстро - [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)

Пишем ботов, парсим и многое другое с супер мощным оружием [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

Для фанатов JS есть [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) можно писать сервер на JS

Answer (score 1):

Начни [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

Приди к [этому](https://nodejs.org/en/)

+много ютюба и разных `а+б=с` написанных тобою, решающих рядовые задачи

Вообще самый простой маршрут, это практика и тыканье через парсеры, качаешь [например](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld), затем при помощи jq тыкаешься в сайты, вк\стим\стак оверфлоу, дополнительный функционал или банальный подсчет... По необходимости(24\7 по сто раз на дню) гуглишь, что-то не знаешь - `console.log();` + гугл и всё

Answer (score 1):

Я лично проходил курсы [WayUp](https://wayup.in/) по дизайну, а в последствии и по вёрстке.
В перерывах от курсов изучал много материала на [HTMLbook](http://htmlbook.ru/) и [HTMLacademy](https://htmlacademy.ru/).

Самое важное, это не останавливаться и не ленится при обучении, всегда использовать поисковую систему для поиска ответов на нужный вопрос. Банальный запрос который я делал в поисковик - "как сверстать шапку" и пересмотрел кучу статей, видосов на ютубе и другие источники. В общем, важно - это уметь гуглить непонятные темы, желательно на английском языке, на зарубежных источниках информации просто вагон и тележка. Так же посоветую курсы на Udemy, там можно брать любой, но не ниже рейтинга 4.7 (личный опыт).

И да, лучше всё таки приобрести курс, хотя бы на Udemy, потому что бесплатное образование не так ценится, как платное :)

Удачи в обучении!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/ - поможет понять основы, и начать самостоятельно развиваться

Comment: Ой. У них слишком много откровенного **внокода в разделе JS. Хотя как быстрый справочник - сойдет.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а определить что это **внокод а что нет ?